# graphql ruby unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm learning Ruby on Rails with GraphQL and following this tutorial: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-ruby/3-mutations/
I'm at the last part about writing a unit test and I ran into an error while running `bundle exec rails test` Here are some of my files like the tutorial

`app > graphql > mutations > base_mutation.rb`

```
module Mutations
  # class BaseMutation < GraphQL::Schema::RelayClassicMutation
    # argument_class Types::BaseArgument
    # field_class Types::BaseField
    # input_object_class Types::BaseInputObject
    # object_class Types::BaseObject
  # end
  class BaseMutation < GraphQL::Schema::Mutation
    null false
  end
end
```

`app > graphql > mutations > create_link.rb`

```
module Mutations
    class CreateLink < BaseMutation
        argument :description, String, required: true
        argument :url, String, required: true

        type Types::LinkType

        def resolve(description: nil, url: nil)
            Link.create!(
                description: description,
                url: url,
            )
        end
    end
end
```

`app > graphql > types > mutation_type.rb`

```
module Types
  class MutationType < Types::BaseObject
    field :create_link, mutation: Mutations::CreateLink
  end
end
```

`test > graphql > mutations > create_link_test.rb`

```
require 'test_helper'

class Mutations::CreateLinkTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    def perform(user: nil, **args)
        Mutations::CreateLink.new(object: nil, field: nil, context: {}).resolve(args)
    end

    test 'create link' do
        link = perform(
            url: 'example',
            description: 'example', 
        )

        assert link.persisted?
        assert_equal link.description, 'example'
        assert_equal link.url, 'example'
    end
end
```

This is the error I ran into:

```
Error:
Mutations::CreateLinkTest#test_create_link:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
    app/graphql/mutations/create_link.rb:8:in `resolve'
    test/graphql/mutations/create_link_test.rb:5:in `perform'
    test/graphql/mutations/create_link_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:CreateLinkTest>'
```

When I delete the `args` argument from the `resolve` call the error is gone but my test fails because I assume it's not passing the `'example'` arguments to the `resolve` call, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In Ruby 3 you need to use a double splat when delegating keyword arguments `.resolve(**args)`.  https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/

Comment: Thank you! The double splat worked!